# Could not find Elements context; You need to wrap the part of your app that calls useStripe() in an <Elements> provider

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe Payment gatway using laravel inertia react. below is my Component and my Controller code. when i click on choose plan button i want it to execute stripe payment. i provide you welcome component Price card component and controller. please provide me the best solution

```
export default function Welcome
let PricingCard = ({ id, name, price, description, duration }) 


    import Navbar from "@/Components/Wesite/Navbar";
    import Carousal from "@/Components/Wesite/Carousel";
    import Cards from "@/Components/Wesite/Cards";
    import { Link, Head, usePage } from "@inertiajs/react";
    import PricingCard from "@/Components/Wesite/Pricing";
    import FooterBrand from "@/Components/Wesite/Footer";
    import { useState } from "react";
    export default function Welcome(props) {
        const { image, memberships } = usePage().props;
    
        const { class_3, class_4, class_5, phone, message, location } = image;
    
        const [membershipCards, setMemberShipCards] = useState(memberships);
    
        return (
            <>
                <Head title="Home" />
                <div className="h-screen  bg-gray-900">
                    <section className="">
                        <Navbar props={props} />
                    </section>
                    <section className="h-full w-full bg-gray-900">
                        <div className="relative h-full">
                            <Carousal props={image} />
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section className="w-full bg-gray-900">
                        <div className="text-center p-10">
                            <div className="uppercase text-theme-orange text-2xl font-[700]">
                                Why Chose us ?
                            </div>
                            <div className="uppercase text-white text-[32px] font-[600]">
                                PUSH YOUR LIMITS FORWARD
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="container h-full mx-auto p-10">
                            <div className="w-full flex gap-3 flex-auto">
                                <Cards
                                    props={class_3}
                                    title="Modern equipment"
                                    description="
                                    Exercise equipment is any apparatus or device used during physical activity to enhance the strength or conditioning effects of that exercise by providing either fixed or adjustable amounts of resistance, or to otherwise enhance the experience or outcome of an exercise routine."
                                />
                                <Cards
                                    props={class_4}
                                    title="Healthy nutrition plan"
                                    description="
                                    Exercise equipment is any apparatus or device used during physical activity to enhance the strength or conditioning effects of that exercise by providing either fixed or adjustable amounts of resistance, or to otherwise enhance the experience or outcome of an exercise routine."
                                />
                                <Cards
                                    props={class_5}
                                    title="Proffesponal training plan"
                                    description=" Exercise equipment is any apparatus or device used during physical activity to enhance the strength or conditioning effects of that exercise by providing either fixed or adjustable amounts of resistance, or to otherwise enhance the experience or outcome of an exercise routine."
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section className="w-full bg-gray-900">
                        <div className="text-center p-10">
                            <div className="uppercase text-theme-orange text-2xl font-[700]">
                                OUR PLAN
                            </div>
                            <div className="uppercase text-white text-[32px] font-[600]">
                                CHOOSE YOUR PRICING PLAN
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="container mx-auto p-10">
                            <div className="w-full flex gap-3 flex-grow justify-evenly flex-wrap">
                                {membershipCards.map((item, index) => (
                                    <PricingCard
                                        key={index}
                                        id={item.id}
                                        name={item.name}
                                        price={item.price}
                                        description={item.description}
                                        duration={item.duration}
                                    />
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
    
                    <section className="w-full bg-gray-900 text-white">
                        <div className="container flex justify-between p-5 mx-auto">
                            <div className="flex gap-2 items-center">
                                <div>
                                    <img src={location} alt="" width="65px" />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    333 Middle Winchendon Rd, Rindge, NH 03461
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex gap-2 items-center">
                                <div>
                                    <img src={phone} alt="" width="65px" />
                                </div>
                                <div>125-711-811 125-668-886</div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex gap-2 items-center">
                                <div>
                                    <img src={message} alt="" width="65px" />
                                </div>
                                <div>Support.gymcenter@gmail.com</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <FooterBrand />
                    </section>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }


    import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { Card } from "flowbite-react";
    import { useState } from "react";
    
    let PricingCard = ({ id, name, price, description, duration }) => {
        const stripe = useStripe();
        const elements = useElements();
        const [planId, setPlanId] = useState({
            membership_plan_id: id,
        });
    
        const handleSubscription = async () => {
            const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.confirmCardSetup({
                payment_method: {
                    card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
                    billing_details: {
                        name: "Card Holder Name",
                    },
                },
            });
    
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                const response = await axios.post("/member/buy-subscription", {
                    payment_method: setupIntent.payment_method,
                    price_id: id, // This should correspond to the Stripe plan ID
                }).then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                });
            }
        };
    
        return (
            <Card>
                <h5 className="mb-4 text-xl font-medium text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                    {name}
                </h5>
                <div className="flex items-baseline text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                    <span className="text-3xl font-semibold">$</span>
                    <span className="text-5xl font-extrabold tracking-tight">
                        {price}
                    </span>
                    <span className="ml-1 text-xl font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                        /{duration} month
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div className="my-7 space-y-5">
                    <div className="w-[300px]">{description}</div>
                </div>
    
                <form onSubmit={handleSubscription}>
                    <CardElement options={{ style: { base: { fontSize: "16px" } }} />
                    <button
                        className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-lg bg-theme-orange px-5 py-2.5 text-center text-sm font-medium text-white hover-bg-theme-orange focus-outline-none focus-ring-4 focus-ring-cyan-200 dark-focus-ring-cyan-900"
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={!stripe}
                    >
                        <p>Choose plan</p>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </Card>
        );
    };
    
    export default PricingCard;
        <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Services\MembershipService;
    use Exception;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    
    class MemberController extends Controller
    {
        protected $membershipService;
        public function __construct(MembershipService $membershipService)
        {
            $this->membershipService = $membershipService;
        }
    
        public function buySubScription(Request $request)
        {
            if (Auth::check()) {
                $user = auth()->user();
                $priceId = $request->input('price_id'); // Stripe Plan ID
                $paymentMethod = $request->input('payment_method');
    
                try {
                    // Create the subscription
                    $user->subscription('default')->create($priceId, $paymentMethod);
    
                    return response()->json(['success' => true]);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
                }
            } else {
                return to_route('login');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you need to wrap the PricingCard with Elements provider under a wrapper say PricingWrapper, can you import Elements from @stripe/react-stripe-js. Provide the stripe promise to the Element provider. And instead of rendering PricingCard, render PricingWrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's in a part of your code you haven't shown, you don't appear to be using the `<Elements />` provider around your use of the react-stripe-js components as shown in the usage example:
https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js#using-hooks

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_123');

const options = {
  mode: 'payment',
  amount: 1099,
  currency: 'usd',
  // Fully customizable with appearance API.
  appearance: {
    /*...*/
  },
};

const App = () => (
  <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
    <CheckoutForm />
  </Elements>
);
```